# How to Print the value on Uitextfield With tag?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have a textfield with tag.Following loop creates 20 textfield.

```
txt_Pos_Y =20;

for (j=0; j<20; j++) {

if (j<20) {
txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, txt_Pos_Y, 100, 15)];
txtField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txtField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
txtField.tag = j;
txtField.placeholder = @"Enter Value";
txtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txtField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
txtField.delegate = self;
[scrollView addSubview:txtField];
[txtField release];  
}
}


-(void)CalculateMethod{

txtField.tag = 1;


double a;

a = Var_sqFt * Var_sqMtr;

txtField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.4f",a];    
}
```

in CalculateMethod() I want to show the value of "a" in   txtField.text , but i am not able to print the value on  txtField.tag = 1;

The value is showing at the bottom textfeild  means   txtField.tag =19;

i want to show the value of "a" on the  txtField.tag = 1 Textfield.

like this

txtField.tag = 1
txtField.text.tag = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.4f",a];

how to do this?

Comment: you must try and be concise as well as comprehensive in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
-(void)CalculateMethod {
    UITextField *txtFld = (UITextField*)[scrollView viewWithTag:1];
    double a;
    a = Var_sqFt * Var_sqMtr;
    txtFld.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.4f",a];
}
```

Comment: @deanWombourne you have earned lot of repo now let me take the privilege :D

Comment: not working, result showing on console but nothing now  showing on any textfield.

Comment: have you checked the values of `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.4f",a]` or `a` ??

Comment: How is the result showing on the console - no code here has an `NSLog` in - what have you changed?

Comment: sir i used nslog in my code now...Thats why result is showing on the console,Sir now the result is showing  but outside the textfiled. Means the result is showing exactly the position where i wanted but i dont know why this is showing outside the textfield? result is showing outside the textfield on the label,which is before the textfield but showing exactly where i wanted.now i want to show the result in the textfiled i used your code.

Comment: This code actually override my Label which i used just before the Uitextfiled, and the result showing on the position where i wanted the tag is working perfectly fine now but i am not able to understand why result are not showing inside the textfeid and why it ovverride my label?

Comment: Have you given your text field and your label the same `tag` by mistake - `viewWithTag:` just returns the first view that has the tag you asked for - it won't check to see if you have more than one with the same tag.

Comment: please dont tag the label, as if you by mistake have given same tag to both textField and label then `viewByTag:` will return the unexpected view which may be your lable or text field.

Comment: yes You are right sir , I gave my label lbl.tag = i; & txtFld.tag = j; on tag 3 both are available , label and TextField , but i gave different tag like "i & j". lbl.tag = i; & txtFld.tag = j;

Comment: give your `label.tag = 100 + i;` and remember that from `100` onwards you have labels

Comment: If i do not use tag on label i have to define every label , and i have many labels and textfileds now how to solve this problem? If i use both the result is conflicting, now what should i do? Please help

Comment: If you give your label a tag of 3 and you give your textfield a tag of 3, when you say `scrollView, please give me the view with tag 3` how do you expect it to know which one to give you? You have to give all your views a unique tag number.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore has the easiest solution :)

Comment: wow , what a gr8 solution sir... I used and the code is perfectly working now , sir i have noone to help me but You people are very nice and gr8, You both.Good people are still on the earth....Thank You Soooooo much...Happy coding...

Comment: deanWombourne & me good people :) thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

**VERSION #1**

```
NSMutableDictionary *textFieldsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; // SPOt THe DIFFERENCE HERE

CGFloat txt_Pos_Y =20;

for (int j=0; j<20; j++) {
    UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, txt_Pos_Y, 100, 15)];
    txtField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    txtField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
    txtField.tag = j;
    txtField.placeholder = @"Enter Value";
    txtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txtField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    txtField.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview:txtField];
    [textFieldsDictionary setObject:txtField forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", j]]; // SPOT THE DIFFERENCE HERE
    [txtField release];
}
```

and:

```
-(void)CalculateMethod{
    UITextField *txtField = [textFieldsDictionary valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1]];
    double a = 3.1415f;
    txtField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.4f", a]; 
}
```

---

**VERSION #2**

you should change this method only.

```
-(void)CalculateMethod{
    UITextField *txtField = nil;
    for (id temporarySubView in scrollView.subviews) {
        if ([temporarySubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            if (((UITextField *)temporarySubView).tag == 1) {
                txtField = temporarySubView;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

   double a = 3.1415f;
   txtField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.4f", a];
}
```